# Windows- Can't start Git: Probably the path to Git executable is not valid

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github

```
Can't start Git: C:\Users\Cloudion PC\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_d93ee8917cfa9add886773e6be9ec08609a502b6\bin\git.exe Probably the path to Git executable is not valid.
```

I am getting the above message which is related to the git in android studio for windows.so far I am using android studio without any problem for last couple of months. now I am getting this all the time I type the code.

```
`C:\Users\Cloudion\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_d93ee8917cfa9add886773e6be9ec08609a502b6\bin\git.exe`
```

but now I cant find `git.exe` at the above. What happened? Does the location change?

Comment: Please provide more details on what do you enter and get this message?
Did you add this project as a git repo recently?

Comment: While typing code. this popup  is showing up

Comment: Try Test the Path to git executable [Preferences>Version Control>Git]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

finally I got it. the location of git.exe is changed from 
`C:\Users\Cloudion\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_d93ee8917cfa9add886773e6be9ec08609a502b6\bin\git.exe`

to

```
C:\Users\CloudionPC\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_c7e0cbde92ba565cb218a521411d0e854079a28c\mingw32\bin\git.exe
```

Comment: Well do not look for git.exe in AppData or subfolders..it would keep changing

Comment: but there is no Github folders inside programFiles

Comment: please try install git from https://git-scm.com/downloads and then you'll find the folder as displayed in the answer.

Answer (score 7):

You need to set your Path to git executable to the folder where the git is installed on your system. Something like C:\Users\ProgramFiles....
[image]
The current path if you can see is not a good place to be. And every time you type a line of code Aandroi Studio seeks for the Git executable to trace the changes in the repo.

Comment: I already set this path as C:\Users\Cloudion PC\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_d93ee8917cfa9add886773e6be9ec08609a502b6\bin\git.exe and using it without any problem for months. but suddenly now I am getting this error message

Comment: But now I cant find git.exe at that location

Comment: AppData is not the correct place to access the executable..
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299098.aspx
You must have the executable on your system. Okay try this, In android studio(opening the same project) : Terminal > git status > share the output

Comment: 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: this is the output I am getting

Comment: You need to install git then, there you go https://git-scm.com/downloads. Then add the path as stated to your android studio.

Comment: you need to ensure that Git is there in your C:\Program Files\ where the executable exist. If installing the Desktop manager installs `git.exe` by itself it should already be there. Look into your C:\Program Files\. If its not there then install from the link provided. It wouldn't replace anything.

Comment: git.exe was there before . but I dont know suddenly what happened.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96262/discussion-between-nullpointer-and-bearded-beast).

Answer (score 3):

After installing GitHubDesktop: https://desktop.github.com/,
depending on your version, the location looks like:

```
C:\Users\YOUR-USER-NAME\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\app-0.5.3\resources\app\git\mingw64\bin\git.exe
```

In the Android Studio event console you can click on +Fix it+ link, right after `Can't start Git: git.exe Probably the path to Git executable is not valid.` message. This brings you to the setting window to enter the full path to the git.exe

Answer (score 2):

Type which git in your terminal/cmd (find out the git path)

```
which git
```

It will give you the original path, where it is installed. Then pass/set that path in your android studio and then click test button. It will be shown success.

My mistake was, previously I had a path like `/usr/bin/git` It doesn't work.
Then

```
which git
```

It gave the correct path. `/usr/local/bin/git`

FYI, I'm using Mac

Answer (score 0):

You first need to install git into your system if it is not already installed, check this [link](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/install-git#windows) where you find download link and installing steps.

After successful installation you need to set the path of git.exe, So follow this:

> File-> Setting-> Version Control -> Select Git From list-> in the
>   right panel add path of git.exe in front of Path to Git executable

It was `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe` in my case. click on test to check and then apply and  ok.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to open the executable from the following directory:

```
C:\Users\YOUR-USER-NAME\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\app-0.5.3\resources\app\git\mingw64\bin\git.exe
```