# Unable to fix "Can't start Git:git.exe" error in windows 10

Tags: android, git

I get the following error **"Can't start Git:git.exe"** while importing any project in android studio. Please help.

Comment: Look the path is correct, please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33939793/windows-cant-start-git-probably-the-path-to-git-executable-is-not-valid/33940999)

Comment: I can't find Git folder in program files

Comment: You need to install git in your pc first. get git from here https://git-scm.com/downloads

Comment: I'll try it ..thanks